# Nested Abstract Class with Override

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract-class, abstraction

I have an abstract class I use to store information about OAuth Tokens:

```
public abstract class Provider
{
    private readonly string _accessToken;
    private readonly string _refreshToken;
    private readonly JsonMeta _providerMeta;

    protected Provider(TokenProfile profile)
    {
        _accessToken = profile.AccessToken;
        _refreshToken = profile.RefreshToken;
        _providerMeta = 
                  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonMeta>(profile.JsonMeta);
    }
    protected class JsonMeta {}
}
```

I use this base class to create subclasses with more specific properties:

```
public class SalesforceProvider : Provider
{
    public SalesforceProvider(TokenProfile profile) : base(profile)
    {
    }
    //Get unique information from the Json
    protected new class JsonMeta
    {
        public string instance_url;
        public string token_type;
        public string id_token;
    }
    //Salesforce calls must be made to a specific server associated
    //with the users account. Most OAuth calls contain unique
    //metadata like this in their responses that is needed to
    //use their service
    public string SomeData()
    {
        return Salesforce.Leads(_providerMeta.instance_url);
    }
}
```

However, the above doesn't work, as `JsonMeta` is implemented in the abstract class and the properties implemented in the class don't exist until we get to the derived class, so the `JsonMeta` object in the derived class is devoid of properties.

But my issue is, the class name and instantiation are going to be the same for each derived class, it's just the properties that will change based on the metadata in the JSON return.

So my question is, can I have an empty class in my abstract that gets instantiated in the abstract constructor to reduce repetition, but does so with the properties present in the derived class?

If not, what is the best way to do something like this?

Comment: How and when the JsonMeta is used after it is initialized?

Comment: Make the abstract class generic?

Comment: @WiktorZychla In salesforces case, I have data access methods that need information like `instance_url` to make REST API calls, so I'll have a public method in the SalesforceProvider that gets a private reference to `instance_url` in the method.

Comment: By the way, the class names are not the same. They may appear the same, but they cannot have the same fully-qualified name, which is what the compiler uses.

Comment: @WiktorZychla example added to question

Answer (score 2):

**Make JsonMeta abstract.**

```
public abstract class Provider
{
    private readonly JsonMeta _providerMeta;

    protected Provider(TokenProfile profile, JsonMeta json)
    {
        // do stuff with JsonMeta object
    }

    protected abstract class JsonMeta { }
}

public class SalesforceProvider : Provider
{
    public SalesforceProvider(TokenProfile profile)
        : base(profile, new SalesforceJson())
    { }

    private class SalesforceJson : JsonMeta
    {
        // Salesforce-specific stuff
    }
}
```

This allows you to create different JSON implementations for different types, but still abstract out their use to the `Provider` base class.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this (I didn't know what the type of profile.JsonMeta was.)

```
public abstract class Provider
{
    private readonly string _accessToken;
    private readonly string _refreshToken;
    private readonly object _jsonMeta;

    protected Provider(TokenProfile profile)
    {
        _accessToken = profile.AccessToken;
        _refreshToken = profile.RefreshToken;
        _jsonMeta = profile.JsonMeta;
    }
    protected JsonMeta ProviderMeta
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonMeta>(_jsonMeta); ;
        }
    }
    protected class JsonMeta { }
}
```

Comment: profile.JsonMeta is a string that is the raw JSON output of an OAuth token response.

Comment: You could store just the profile data in the base class, and have the Json calls in the child classes.  If you didn't want to deserialize each time, create a protected JsonMeta in the base class, and set to null.  The first time ProviderMeta is called from a child class, that JsonMeta property can be filled.